# Several important forders missing in SSD with Windows

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery, recovery

I've read about missing files due to SSD wear-out, hidden files, accidentally deleted files and such but I thing this problem might be different.

One day a friend's computer was missing a boot device, when I checked her SSD (Micron M500 2.5 SSD) in my Linux computer I found only the folders `System Volume Information` and `$RECYCLE.BIN`, nothing else.

Then I run `sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sda1 --scan` thinking that somehow she managed to delete all those Windows/Users folders but nothing showed up to be recovered

```
Inode    Flags  %age     Date    Time       Size  Filename
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
16       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
17       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
18       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
19       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
20       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
21       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
22       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
23       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
43       D...     0%  2022-09-03 21:28         0  CrystalDiskMark0552BE49
44       FN..   100%  2022-09-03 21:32 1073741824  CrystalDiskMark0552BE49.tmp
45       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
46       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
47       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
48       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
49       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
50       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
51       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
52       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
53       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
54       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
55       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
56       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
57       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
58       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
59       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
60       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
61       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
62       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
63       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
64       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
65       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
66       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
67       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
68       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
69       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
70       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
71       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
72       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
73       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
74       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
75       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
76       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
77       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
78       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
79       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
80       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
81       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
82       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
83       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
84       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
85       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
86       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
87       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
88       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
89       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
90       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
91       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
92       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
93       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
94       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
95       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
96       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
97       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
98       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
99       F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
100      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
101      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
102      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
103      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
104      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
105      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
106      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
107      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
108      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
109      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
110      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
111      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
112      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
113      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
114      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
115      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
116      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
117      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
118      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
119      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
120      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
121      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
122      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
123      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
124      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
125      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
126      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
127      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
128      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
129      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
130      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
131      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
132      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
133      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
134      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
135      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
136      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
137      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
138      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
139      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
140      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
141      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
142      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
143      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
144      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
145      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
146      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
147      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
148      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
149      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
150      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
151      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
152      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
153      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
154      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
155      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
156      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
157      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
158      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
159      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
160      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
161      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
162      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
163      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
164      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
165      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
166      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
167      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
168      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
169      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
170      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
171      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
172      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
173      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
174      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
175      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
176      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
177      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
178      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
179      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
180      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
181      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
182      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
183      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
184      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
185      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
186      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
187      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
188      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
189      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
190      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
191      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
192      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
193      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
194      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
195      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
196      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
197      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
198      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
199      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
200      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
201      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
202      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
203      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
204      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
205      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
206      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
207      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
208      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
209      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
210      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
211      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
212      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
213      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
214      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
215      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
216      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
217      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
218      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
219      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
220      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
221      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
222      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
223      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
224      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
225      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
226      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
227      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
228      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
229      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
230      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
231      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
232      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
233      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
234      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
235      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
236      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
237      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
238      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
239      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
240      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
241      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
242      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
243      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
244      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
245      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
246      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
247      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
248      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
249      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
250      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
251      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
252      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
253      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
254      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>
255      F..!     0%  1969-12-31 21:00         0  <none>

Files with potentially recoverable content: 1
```

Thinking about a SSD wear-out I checked for "S.M.A.R.T" support

```
$ sudo smartctl --info /dev/sda | grep 'SMART support is:'

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

and run a "long" test but it showed "PASSED"

```
$ sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda
$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda

smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-5.18.16-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Any idea of what other tests can I run to see if there are any files left in the device to recover?

**EDIT**: Adding info about full SMART report

```
$sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
 
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-5.18.16-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron Client SSDs
Device Model:     Micron_M500_MTFDDAK240MAV
Serial Number:    14350D60F317
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 10d60f317
Firmware Version: MU05
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Sep 13 16:59:51 2022 -03
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 1115) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  18) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       15
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       13002
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5781
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       262
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       158
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       4064
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   075   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       25 (Min/Max 0/45)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
197 Current_Pending_ECC_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       756
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain 0x0031   092   092   000    Pre-fail  Offline      -       8
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       37884038291
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1284157884
248 FTL_Program_Page_Count  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2794043982

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 0 inconsistent with error log pointer 1

ATA Error Count: 0
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 0 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 1c 6a 65 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00656a1c = 6646300

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 1c 6a 65 40 00  31d+11:36:00.000  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 bc 1e a6 40 00  31d+11:36:00.000  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 b4 1e a6 40 00  31d+11:36:00.000  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 08 ac 1e a6 40 00  31d+11:36:00.000  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 08 a4 1e a6 40 00  31d+11:36:00.000  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     13000         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13000         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12993         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12992         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12991         -
# 6  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     12991         -
# 7  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8755         -
# 8  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8752         -
# 9  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8715         -
#10  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8604         -
#11  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8601         -
#12  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8259         -
#13  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7635         -
#14  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7608         -
#15  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7550         -
#16  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7339         -
#17  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7298         -
#18  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7279         -
#19  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      6876         -
#20  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      4453         -
#21  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      3170         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: I would try starting (booting) with a Windows 10 ISO (use Rufus to make it) and see if you see Windows this way. Your test above says Windows is gone but that may or may not be true. A decent SSD will last many years.

Comment: I'm not sure how booting from Windows will show more files than the shown now but I'll give it a try!

Comment: If booting from Windows does not show more files, something has wrecked the operating system

Comment: I installed windows in a spare notebook and plugged the SSD as USB and nothing showed up, it's almost as if the SSD had a fresh format

Comment: You will need to reinstall Windows as something has gone very wrong.

Comment: Reinstalling windows is not the problem, recovering the "deleted" files is the problem

Comment: You would need Recuva or something like that to recover files.

Comment: Could you post the full SMART report (`smartctl -a`)?

Comment: @PierU I edited the post to include the full report 

Comment: @John I tried `ntfsundelete` to check for deleted files but it showed no results. I'll give `Recuva` a try anyways, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You may have lost your data.  See what Recuva says.

Comment: SSD wear doesn't cause files to disappear - it switches drive into read-only mode. How many partitions are there on the drive?

Comment: @AronNeewart I have a Micron SSD too. Your disk has only 262 write/erase cycles on average, which is similar to mine and far from the design lifespan. However your SSD shows some problems : the fields 1, 5, 187, 196, 199, have all a zero raw values on my SSD. In particular, having non zero "reported uncorrected" is a bad sign...

Comment: @PierU I had to read a (post)[https://wiki.unraid.net/Understanding_SMART_Reports] first to understand the answer. It seems that every attribute is within its healthy range though. Actually it seems too good which is even more odd for it to lose so much data all at once.

Comment: @John I just tried Recuva but it found 0 files :( It really is as if someone grabbed this SSD, zero-filled, formatted and copied the two folders I initially found. I can't imagine any other way of doing this giving it was a normal running laptop with a healthy SSD.

Comment: Nothing more now you can do. So reinstall Windows and the data is gone.  You can try taking the SSD to a recovery agency but that is normally expensive.

Comment: Please check if the drive contains other partitions. You may be looking at the wrong one.

Comment: That's true that all attributes are within the OK range, but the fact is that it has already experienced anomalies. If it was mine I would replace it. That said, it can hardly explain a total loss a data. I agree with @gronostaj, you should check possible other partitions.

Comment: Indeed it has another small partition but I assume it's a recovery partition or something like that, I run the tests in the bigger one of ~230GB NTFS which most likely seemed to be the Windows one

Comment: Did she format drive at any point? It looks like it. If so then depending on exactly how she did TRIM commands may have been sent which would explain why data recovery tool comes up empty handed. May want to double check with for example DMDE.